# Linker command Failed with Exit code 1 : Google Maps

Tags: swift, google-maps

Im trying to use google Maps and when i try to add a map to my view i get this error when i run the program :

```
Linker command Failed with Exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do i fix this?

This is the podfile i'm using

```
 # platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FlexxRide' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use             
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for FlexxRide
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'GooglePlaces'
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Database'

 target 'FlexxRideTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
 end

target 'FlexxRideUITests' do
 inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

After using cocoapods, you need to use the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj` file. The issue should be resovled after you build your project with the `.xcworkspace` file